# Tooltip is not working while accessing value from ts file - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get the value of a tooltip from a ts file, but it's not working; If I try to give a value in html directly, it works. I'm not sure if it's a syntactic problem or something else entirely. Please assist me in comprehending the situation.

My Html file code:

```html
<a class="contactDetails">               
    <ibm-icon-email [size]="20" title="Contact us:{{cDetails}}">        </ibm-icon-email>          
</a>
```

Ts file:

```js
export class HelpComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
cDetails = 'XYZ@mailaddress.com';
}
```

Comment: Add the title to the a-tag instead of only the icon. Would make for better accessibility too.

Comment: refer this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular2/angular2_data_display.htm

Comment: what is ibm-icon-email component custom or library?

Comment: @mr.pc_coder it's an Carbon design system external library, which I was using for icon

Comment: Is your tooltip lib compatible with angular ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler If I pass direct value for tooltip in html file it self, then that is coming properly which means tooltip is compatible with angular